# "try-catch" or "throws" to manage exceptions inside a Web service method?

Tags: java, web-services, exception

Can you guys tell me the good way to manage exceptions in web services methods? (SOAP/REST/..)

Can you tell me the advantages and drawbackes in case of :

- Using Try-Catch block and sending an error code. For example in case of REST :

  ```
  try{
      // something that triggers exception here...
      return javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(500).build();
  }catch(..){
  }
  ```
- Using adding `throws MyException` in the prototype of the web service method

Thank you so much!

Comment: IMHO . There is nothing wrong having try catch in your rest method. It is purely depends on your business case what http code needs to be sent to client ( Resource Not Found / 403 forbidden / Http Sucess status with business error )

Answer (score 0):

No real advantage or disadvantage. It depends on what implementation you want.
If its an internal implementation then i would throw back exception itself so that people calling webservice knows exact details of error.

If i am working web service for 3rd party, i would prefer returning code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Try-Catch you will catch any exceptions inside the method where the Try-Catch is. Using throws MyException you will throw the exception higher up in the hierarchy, meaning that the class/scope using your method will have to do something about the exception.

Generally these are good pointers:

1. catch an exception only if you can handle it in a meaningful way
2. declare throwing the exception upward if it is to be handled by the 
   consumer of the current
3. throw exceptions if they are caused by the input parameters (but
   these are more often unchecked)

In your case I would probably use a Try-Catch and do something meaningful with the exception, maybe route the user to a error message.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion its always better to handle exception in Webservices with proper error codes. EvenIf you throw a custom exception finally it reaches the client as a SOAP fault exception. So it would be better to follow the following guidelines inorder to expose a better webservice:

- Identify the possible errors and assign error codes and valid descriptions. This will help you to differentiate between validation errors, Data not found errors, runtime errors etc
- Define your own custom error tags

  `<error>
    <errorCode/>
    <errorDesc/>
  </error>`
- Populate this errors and send it back to the calling application. This will help them to handle the exceptions in their own ways

Its always better to pass meaningful errors as above rather than throwing the generic SOAP fault exception. You can notice this whenever you consume standard webservices